# Использование react native в production

Tags: android, reactjs, ios, react-native, mobile-development

У меня хороший опыт frontend разработчика, интересуюсь переходом в мобильную разработку. Начал изучать react native, вроде он делает все что нужно, хотя и медленно. Хочу услышать мнение от разработчиков мобильных приложений, подходит ли react native для профессиональных приложений (банки, криптокошельки, сервисы аренды...) со множеством экраном и хорошим UI. Или лучше забить на react native и начать учить java (swift).

Comment: Вообще react native - конечно же используется "большими приложениями" и справляется с поставленными задачами, но я думаю все таки лучше смотреть в сторону флатер или котлин мультиплатформ.

Answer (score 0):

В компании используем React для веба и поэтому, когда для одного из проектов  потребовалось полноценное мобильное приложение, решили среди прочих равных выбрать именно react-native, в виду того, что команде потребуется меньше времени на вкатывание.
И что могу сказать. Это было огромной ошибкой. Хоть на react-native и пишут большие комерс-приложения, но нам он показался (до сих пор кажется) очень "специфичным" инструментом.
Сильно много проблем и сырых мест(хотя существует он уже целых 6 лет).Они все решаемые, но времени и нервов съедают знатно.
Недавно решил "потрогать" Flutter + Dart и могу с полной уверенностью сказать, что это намного более удачный выбор.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).